# How to solve 2 libraries with same package name in my dependencies in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have below dependencies in my project:

```
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
     compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
     compile project(':library')
     compile files('libs/volley.jar')
     compile('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+')
```

Now while syncing i got the below error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.maps.android'
>   You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
>   However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

I have tried like below but same error i got:

```
 compile('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

I have also tried like below but error remains:

```
  compile('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3') { transitive = false }
```

I am using the below:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

What Should I do??

Comment: find all the jar files you have in your dependency tree -- dont dupe   then, using gradlew do a "-q dependencies"  and study it for dupe maps . inspect dependencies of ":library" and compare to other sibling projects. for checklist of deduping refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870207/proguard-dupe-zip-entry-after-upgraded-facebook-parse-ui-lib-to-v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried following and it worked:

[image]

So the problem is not at

`compile('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+')`

It duplicates in following lines:

```
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile project(':library')
```

Please check if they included package named `com.google.maps.android`.

Comment: I have my android-maps-utils library in library folder and i have included both map utils library and :library folder in the dependencies.I have just excluded compile project(':library') and it works fine now.Thanks for finding out the problem.